# Including brackets inside text function

Tags: fonts, pdftex, typewriter

I am having a programming function with name `WorkFunction_()`. I am trying to highlight this function using `\texttt{}`, something like `\texttt{WorkFunction_()}`. However this ends in error.

Could anyone suggest an alternate for this?

Comment: `\_` is the command to produce an underscore in LaTeX.

Comment: Solved the problem already with the same.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle an answer, sir? :)

Comment: @cmhughes more likely close as dup if you can find it (must be one somewhere:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think I found the dupe.

Comment: You might also consider using    \verb here instead of    \texttt.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that a `\_` is needed to produce `_` inside `\texttt{}`. The problem is solved with `\texttt{WorkFunction\_()}`. Note the `\` before `_`.

Comment: There are at least two other options: `\verb+WorkFunction_()+`, or load `underscore` and use the normal underscore without need to escape it: `\usepackage{underscore}` and then `\texttt{WorkFunction\_()}`.

Comment: `\textttt` is irrelevant to the problem, you need `\_` (or some other command) anywhere in LaTeX to get `_`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thats a valid point actually :)